# Magnific-Popup does not allow popups within itself to take focus

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, tinymce, magnific-popup

When TinyMCE(or any other WYSIWYG editor) is initialized within a Magnific-Popup it works without issue and you can edit and format HTML. But when you click on the add link or add image button which opens up another popup by TinyMCE, the textfields of the TinyMCE popup cannot take focus and are thus not editable. Is there a Magnific-Popup setting which would allow TinyMCE to take focus within its own popups?

Code is basic:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({items:{src:'#modal'}});
tinymce.init({ selector: '#textarea'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make exclusions for another popup classes, if they are not inside MagnificPopup DOM.
See
[select2 in magnific popup: search input cannot be focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990191/select2-in-magnific-popup-search-input-cannot-be-focused) and
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/280

As the author said:

> When tab focus changes, the popup checks if the new focused element is
> inside the popup. If it is outside, popup sets focus back to the root
> element of popup. This is done to "lock" the tab focus in popup.

A workaround sample for "select2" plugin:

```
$.magnificPopup.instance._onFocusIn = function(e) {
          // Do nothing if target element is select2 input
          if( $(e.target).hasClass('select2-input') ) {
            return true;
          } 
          // Else call parent method
          $.magnificPopup.proto._onFocusIn.call(this,e);
};
```